# Breaking up records into pages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the stored procedure below in SQL Server 2014 to break up the results from a table into pages or files of 240,000 records each. I start with @PageNumber = 1 and then run and integrated services package file (.dtsx) which calls this procedure and exports the records into a .csv file containing 240,000 records.  I then change the @PageNumber = 2, run the .dtsx file again which exports the next .csv file. I repeat this process until I run out of records which often is several million.  Would anyone have any ideas on how to do this without having to change the @PageNumber value and running the .dtsx package multiple times? Thanks

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 1
SET @RowspPage = 240000

SELECT  [SSN]
        ,[DOB]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[FirstName]
        ,[CustomerRecordID]
        ,[ADDate]
        ,[MiddleName] FROM (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS NUMBER,
                 [SSN]
                ,[DOB]
                ,[LastName]
                ,[FirstName]
                ,[CustomerRecordID]
                ,[ADDate]
                ,[MiddleName]
        FROM [dbo].[All Borrowers 20180222]
               ) AS TBL
        WHERE 
            NUMBER BETWEEN ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage + 1) AND 
       (@PageNumber * @RowspPage)
        ORDER BY 
            NUMBER
```

Comment: why don't you use `For Loop Container`?

Comment: there is a while but as far as I know no For Loop...

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits there is a FOR LOPP CONTAINER in SSIS. It is not abundantly clear unless you read the whole question that the OP is running an SSIS package with chunks.

Comment: You are right there is a for loop but usually that is used to look through objects not typically through batches of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT
declare @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 1
SET @RowspPage = 100

declare @more int = 1
while  (@more=1)
begin

SELECT  [SSN]
        ,[DOB]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[FirstName]
        ,[CustomerRecordID]
        ,[ADDate]
        ,[MiddleName] FROM (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS NUMBER,
                 [SSN]
                ,[DOB]
                ,[LastName]
                ,[FirstName]
                ,[CustomerRecordID]
                ,[ADDate]
                ,[MiddleName]
        FROM [dbo].[All Borrowers 20180222]
               ) AS TBL
        WHERE 
            NUMBER BETWEEN ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage + 1) AND 
       (@PageNumber * @RowspPage)
        ORDER BY 
            NUMBER

            if @@rowcount = 0
                break
        set @pagenumber += 1
    end

     This will loop through and stop when you run out of rows (@@rownumber = 0). I am assuming that there always some rows.
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each set of 240000 using something like this:

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 1
SET @RowspPage = 240000

while @PageNumber<=(select count(*) from [dbo].[All Borrowers 20180222])/cast(240000 as float)
begin

SELECT  [SSN]
        ,[DOB]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[FirstName]
        ,[CustomerRecordID]
        ,[ADDate]
        ,[MiddleName] FROM (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS NUMBER,
                 [SSN]
                ,[DOB]
                ,[LastName]
                ,[FirstName]
                ,[CustomerRecordID]
                ,[ADDate]
                ,[MiddleName]
        FROM [dbo].[All Borrowers 20180222]
               ) AS TBL
        WHERE 
            NUMBER BETWEEN ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage + 1) AND 
       (@PageNumber * @RowspPage)
        ORDER BY 
            NUMBER


            set pagenumber=@pagenumber+1
            end
```